Read encoder's data with RPi + ROS2
i'm actually doing a mecanum drive robot that has 4 DC motors (polulu) with encoders.
To drive my robot, I wanted to measure the speed of my motors to adjust the Duty Cycle with a simple PID.
However, as I'm working on it, I saw that the speed I calculated is way far from reality. When my motors are stopped it sometimes shows me that it drives at 100 rps and sometimes at 0 etc...
So could someone help me to find how I could solve this issue ?
Here is the code how calculate the speed of my motors :
   #!/usr/bin/env python3
import rclpy
from rclpy.node import Node
from my_msg.msg import Encoder
import pigpio as GPIO
import time

print("# GPIO pins configuration for encoders - schema on notion")
A_FL = 17 # Yellow = A
B_FL = 4 # White = B
A_FR = 14
B_FR = 15
A_RL = 19
B_RL = 26
A_RR = 20
B_RR = 21

val_PI = 3.14159265359 

PPR = 979.2 # 48 * 20.4 (points per revolution)

print("# Define variables")
T_measurement = 1 # Measurement period

class EncoderNode(Node):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__('encoder_node')   # ROS node initialization
        self.encoder_msg = Encoder()         # Custom message format

        # Counters initialization
        self.pulse_count_A = [0, 0, 0, 0]   
        self.pulse_count_B = [0, 0, 0, 0]

        # Creating topic to publish information
        self.publisher_ = self.create_publisher(Encoder, 'encoder', 10)
        self.prev_time = time.time()

        # Initialize pigpio
        self.pi = GPIO.pi()
        
        # Setting GPIO pins to input mode
        self.pi.set_mode(A_FL, GPIO.INPUT)
        self.pi.set_mode(B_FL, GPIO.INPUT)
        self.pi.set_mode(A_FR, GPIO.INPUT)
        self.pi.set_mode(B_FR, GPIO.INPUT)
        self.pi.set_mode(A_RL, GPIO.INPUT)
        self.pi.set_mode(B_RL, GPIO.INPUT)
        self.pi.set_mode(A_RR, GPIO.INPUT)
        self.pi.set_mode(B_RR, GPIO.INPUT)

        # Adding pull-up resistor for noise reduction
        self.pi.set_pull_up_down(A_FL, GPIO.PUD_UP)
        self.pi.set_pull_up_down(A_FR, GPIO.PUD_UP)
        self.pi.set_pull_up_down(A_RL, GPIO.PUD_UP)
        self.pi.set_pull_up_down(A_RR, GPIO.PUD_UP)
        self.pi.set_pull_up_down(B_FL, GPIO.PUD_UP)
        self.pi.set_pull_up_down(B_FR, GPIO.PUD_UP)
        self.pi.set_pull_up_down(B_RL, GPIO.PUD_UP)
        self.pi.set_pull_up_down(B_RR, GPIO.PUD_UP)      

        # Internal pigpio method to count edges
        self.cbA0 = self.pi.callback(A_FL, GPIO.RISING_EDGE)
        self.cbA1 = self.pi.callback(A_FR, GPIO.RISING_EDGE)
        self.cbA2 = self.pi.callback(A_RL, GPIO.RISING_EDGE)
        self.cbA3 = self.pi.callback(A_RR, GPIO.RISING_EDGE)
        self.cbB0 = self.pi.callback(B_FL, GPIO.RISING_EDGE)
        self.cbB1 = self.pi.callback(B_FR, GPIO.RISING_EDGE)
        self.cbB2 = self.pi.callback(B_RL, GPIO.RISING_EDGE)
        self.cbB3 = self.pi.callback(B_RR, GPIO.RISING_EDGE)

        # Creating a timer with period T_measurement
        self.timer = self.create_timer(T_measurement, self.speed_calcul) 
        
    def speed_calcul(self):
        # Getting values
        pulse_count_A = [self.cbA0.tally(), self.cbA1.tally(), self.cbA2.tally(), self.cbA3.tally()]
        pulse_count_B = [self.cbB0.tally(), self.cbB1.tally(), self.cbB2.tally(), self.cbB3.tally()]
        
        # Calculating elapsed time
        current_time = time.time()
        elapsed_time = current_time - self.prev_time

        # Calculate revolutions per second
        rps = [
            (pulse_count_A[0] + pulse_count_B[0]) / (PPR * elapsed_time),
            (pulse_count_A[1] + pulse_count_B[1]) / (PPR * elapsed_time),
            (pulse_count_A[2] + pulse_count_B[2]) / (PPR * elapsed_time),
            (pulse_count_A[3] + pulse_count_B[3]) / (PPR * elapsed_time)]

        # Publishing data
        self.encoder_msg.w_fl = rps[0] * (2 * val_PI)  # speed value for motor w_fl in rad/s
        self.encoder_msg.w_fr = rps[1] * (2 * val_PI)  # speed value for motor w_fr
        self.encoder_msg.w_rl = rps[2] * (2 * val_PI)  # speed value for motor w_rl
        self.encoder_msg.w_rr = rps[3] * (2 * val_PI)  # speed value for motor w_rr
        self.encoder_msg.time = elapsed_time       # Also publishing time for PID
        self.publisher_.publish(self.encoder_msg)

        # Reset variables for next interval
        self.prev_time = current_time
        self.cbA0.reset_tally()
        self.cbA1.reset_tally()
        self.cbA2.reset_tally()
        self.cbA3.reset_tally()
        self.cbB0.reset_tally()
        self.cbB1.reset_tally()
        self.cbB2.reset_tally()
        self.cbB3.reset_tally()
        self.pulse_count_A = [0, 0, 0, 0]  # Reset just in case
        self.pulse_count_B = [0, 0, 0, 0]


def main():
    print("Initialization")
    rclpy.init()
    encoder_node = EncoderNode()
    rclpy.spin(encoder_node) # And we spin the node, instead of towels

    # Shutdown GPIO
    encoder_node.pi.stop()
    rclpy.shutdown()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        main()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        pass
    finally:
        rclpy.shutdown()


You lose at least some precision due to the fact that time.time() returns the unix time in seconds. Therefore better use time.time_ns().
